# python matplotlib mulitple figures (not subplots) on same pdf with custom arrangment

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a collection of charts I need to put on the same pdf, but they are grouped into different subplot grids like below.

Ex. I have something like

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_rows, num_cols)
fig2, axes2 = plt.subplots(num_rows2, num_cols2)
fig3, axes3 = plt.subplots(num_rows3, num_cols3)
# more figures
```

I'm trying a find a way of arranging the figures in the the pdf in a custom way, similar to what you can do with subplots,

```
fig, axis = plt.subplots(rows, cols)
axis[0, 0].plot(X, Y)
axis[0, 1].plot(X2, Y2)
```

but instead of a grid of axises it would be a grid of figures, and I could tell matplotlib which row or column each figure goes in.

Is there a way to do this? One workaround is to just have one figure and calculate the positions of all the plots manually based on which group there are in, but I'm wondering if there's something built in to matplotlib to do this.

Comment: What is the distinction between `figure` and `subplot` from your point of view?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan a `subplot` would be an individual graph (on a single axis), and a `figure` is the collection of subplots (so fig, fig2, and fig3 would all be figures). I want to combine multiple figures on a larger figure in a grid layout, the same way you can put many subplots on a single figure with plt.subplots

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, for your use case, a `figure` is no different from a `subplot` apart from the fact that they are at a different hierarchy level? You don't want a simple layout, you want a grid layout of other layouts?